# Passing array or list of strings in IN clause of a sql query

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Java, so please forgive me if it is a naive question. I have a string that is in comma separated like this `"str1, str2,str3"` .I need to query data from database that matches that list of strings. I know I can convert `"str1,str2,str3"` to an array. But would also need to pass this in a IN clause of sql query like this

```
 select * from Customer where name IN ('str1','str2','str3')
```

How can I accomplish that since after the conversion of `"str1,str2,str3"` to an array won't be legal to pass it in IN clause?
Any utility method in hibernate that can help taking care of this issue?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What are you using to make your queries? Are you just building your sql-queries as Strings and then send them to the database as native queries?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I am using em.createQuery  to build the query

Comment: Convert the string `str1,str2,str3` into a list and use that list in a prepared statement or hql.

Comment: @aksappy But the problem with that translate to this sql `name IN ([str1,str2,str3])` query which is invalid.Unless I am missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use something like this:

```java
List<Customer> customers = entityManager.createQuery(
    "select c " +
    "from Customer c " +
    "where c.name in :names", Customer.class )
.setParameter( "names", Arrays.asList( "str1", "str2" ) )
.getResultList();
```

See also [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-in-predicate) of hibernate documentation.